PHP: Unable to extact files from a ZIP archive
I am trying to upload a .zip file to a Server and extract it.
First, I move the uploaded .zip file to my $target_path
$target_Path = $path . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_Path);

Then I am trying to unzip the .zip file using ZipArchive in PHP (ZipArchive)
 function unzip($zipFile, $destination) {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $zip->open($zipFile);
                for($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                    $file=$zip->getNameIndex($i);
                    if(substr($file,-1) == '/') continue;
                    $lastDelimiterPos = strrpos($destination.$file, '/');
                    $dir = substr($destination.$file, 0, $lastDelimiterPos);
                    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                    }
                    $name = substr($destination.$file, $lastDelimiterPos + 1);
                    echo $dir. "/" .$name;
                    copy("zip://$zipFile#$file","$dir/$name");
                }

                $zip->close();
            }

            unzip($target_Path, $path);

$target_path is a relative path directly to the .zip file
$path is a relative path to the folder ending in a "/"
Through the Error-Message I know, that my path to the .zip file must be correct (I see the files I want to copy) 
The Error I get:
<br>
copy(zip://../Customer/Test/Screen Links/HTML_Content/WETTERKARTE.zip#WETTERKARTE/alt/fs_panel.svg): Failed to open stream: operation failed in D:\xampp\htdocs\MVM_RED_VIOLET\php\AX_upload_PIC.php on line 60 <br>

So I know that fs_panel.svg (the first file in the ZipArchive) gets found.
I just don´t know how I can copy the file from the ZipArchive to a folder outside.
I also tried zip->extractTo - that only gives me no error but also no files - it just says it worked without doing anything.

The comments and answer on this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918123/php-extracting-files-from-zip-issues-with-copy ) suggest that you should persevere with extractTo rather than using copy.

I'm not sure you can mix ZipArchive with stream wrappers (copy()), there's a chance that the former keeps the file locked. I recommend you choose a tool and stick to it throughout the whole process.

@droopsnoot could be, but I tried using extractTo as in the other question you posted and it didn´t work.

Can you create an empty file by code on the related destination?

Yes - I can create directories and files on my destination path

I could not get the zipArchive to work so I looked for other options...
I solved my problem using shell_exec()
shell_exec("7z x $file -o$path -y 2>&1");

this command uses 7-Zip (which is installed on my Pc) and extracts a $file to my $path
Things you need to set for this to work:

install and add 7-zip to your enviroment variables
change variables_order="GPCS" to variables_order="EGPCS" in your php.ini file
set safe_mode_exec_dir=Off in your php.ini file
add 2>&1 to the end of you command

this setup executes any command you write in your php file in a shell - so if a command works in your shell it should work in php too

Try this:
<?php
function unzip($zipFile, $destination) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    
    // Try to open the zip file
    if ($zip->open($zipFile) === TRUE) {
        // Check if the destination directory exists, if not create it
        if (!file_exists($destination)) {
            mkdir($destination, 0777, true);
        }

        // Extract the contents of the zip file to the destination
        if ($zip->extractTo($destination)) {
            echo "Files extracted successfully to $destination.";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to extract files.";
        }

        // Close the zip archive
        $zip->close();
    } else {
        echo "Failed to open the zip file.";
    }
}

// Example usage
$target_path = $path . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);  // Path where the uploaded zip is saved
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

unzip($target_path, $path);  // Extract the zip file to the destination folder
?>


Your answer would be much more useful if you explained what's wrong in the original code and how you're fixing it.

I just get an error "Failed to extract files." - seems like $zip-> extractTo is not working, but I don´t know why.
